# Splunk addon not working..no logs either

Tags: splunk

I have installed splunk addon on Splunk Enterprise. (cassandra addon). But it seems its not working...I dont see any logs in splunkd.log

I have gone through Addon troubleshooting

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/AddOns/released/Overview/Wheretoinstall

How do i debug if addon is working properly or not ? [image: Addon shows installed]

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's the "Add-on for cassandra cluster monitoring"
https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/2780/#/details

Did you follow the author instructions?
"You have to Install this add on in each node in cluster and enable scripts in inputs.conf. These scripts are written in perl so you should have perl installed in each node in cluster. Set destination ip address(indexer) in outputs.conf file."

1. Did you install the addon on a forwarder, in nodes of the cluster?
2. Did you enable scripts in inputs.conf?
3. Did you install the full cassandra app in the splunk search head?
   https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/2779/#/details

Comment: Yes..Did all that...It's seems add-on author has hard-codes path ...Also ..Add-on won't work on universal forwarder. ...Answer on splunk answer website....Very confusin stuff...Still not sure what exactly works on light weight forwarder...

Comment: If it won't work on universal forwarder, then on what hosts did you install the add-on? is it installed on nodes of the cluster?

If so, try to run the scripts from inputs.conf manually on cmd or shell and see if it return results.